# Check whether a list contain an attribute of an object in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to check whether `myItemsList` contains `myitem.itemId` or not, If it exists need to add `itemQuantity`, if it not exists need to add `myitem` object to `myItemsList`.

```
List<MyItem> myItemsList = new List();

MyItem myitem = new MyItem (
  itemId: id,
  itemName: name,
  itemQuantity: qty,
);

if (myItemsList.contains(myitem.itemId)) {
  print('Already exists!');
} else {
  print('Added!');
  setState(() {
    myItemsList.add(myitem);
  });
}
```

`MyItem` class

```
class MyItem {
  final String itemId;
  final String itemName;
  int itemQuantity;

  MyItem ({
    this.itemId,
    this.itemName,
    this.itemQuantity,
  });
}
```

above code is not working as expected, please help me to figure out the issue.

Comment: You're calling `myItemsList.contains(String)`, but `myItemsList` doesn't contain `String`s; it contains `MyItem`s.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Contains() compares the whole objects.

Besides overriding == operator or looping over, you can use list's singleWhere method:

```
  if ((myItemsList.singleWhere((it) => it.itemId == myitem.itemId,
          orElse: () => null)) != null) {
```

Edit:
As Dharaneshvar experienced and YoApps mentioned in the comments .singleWhere raises StateError when more elements are found.

This is desired when you expect unique elements such as in the case of comparing IDs.

Raised error is the friend here as it shows that there is something wrong with the data.

For other cases .firstWhere() is the right tool:

```
  if ((myItemsList.firstWhere((it) => it.itemName == myitem.itemName,
          orElse: () => null)) != null) {
```

// EO Edit

Whole example:

```
List<MyItem> myItemsList = new List();
​
class MyItem {
  final String itemId;
  final String itemName;
  int itemQuantity;
​
  MyItem({
    this.itemId,
    this.itemName,
    this.itemQuantity,
  });
}
​
void main() {
  MyItem myitem = new MyItem(
    itemId: "id00",
    itemName: "name",
    itemQuantity: 50,
  );
​
  myItemsList.add(myitem);
​
  String idToCheck = "id00";
​
  if ((myItemsList.singleWhere((it) => it.itemId == idToCheck,
          orElse: () => null)) != null) {
    
    print('Already exists!');
  } else {
    print('Added!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Recently getting "Bad State: too many elements error" in Flutter after upgrading. Is there any changes to do or is there any alternative way to do this check?

Comment: @Dharaneshvar  I wonder what is the code throwing that.

Comment: EXACTLY! Thats why I would NOT recommend **.singleWhere()** .. but instead **firstWhere()**. Because if more than 1 element is found it will throw StateError. But **firstWhere()** will just return you that element or execute the orElse: block of code!

Comment: @YoApps I updated the answer to reflect when to use singleWhere vs firstWhere

Answer (score 38):

As already said before, contains compares two Objects with the == operator. So you currently compare `MyItem` with `String itemId`, which will never be the same.

To check whether myItemsList contains myitem.itemId you can use one of the following:

```
myItemsList.map((item) => item.itemId).contains(myitem.itemId);
```

or

```
myItemsList.any((item) => item.itemId == myitem.itemId);
```

Answer (score 11):

You're using contains slightly wrong.

From: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html

```
bool contains(Object element) {
  for (E e in this) {
    if (e == element) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

You can either override the `==` operator, see: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/hash_and_equals.html

```
@override    
bool operator ==(Object other) => other is Better && other.value == value;
```

Or you can loop over your list and search the normal way one by one, which seems slightly easier.

Answer (score 4):

One more way to check does list contain object with property or not

```
if (myList.firstWhereOrNull((val) => val.id == someItem.id) != null) {}
```

Comment: Make sure to add this import statement when using `firstWhereOrNull`:
`import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; `