# How to use contains with a list in dart

Tags: dart

Hi i have list of objects and i would like to check if a certain object is in the list
i have the following code

```dart
List<GladiatorOutput> gladiators = await Obstructionum.utDifficultas(principalisDirectory);
for (GladiatorOutput gladiator in gladiators) {
  print(gladiator.toJson());
}
print(gladiatorToAttack.outputs[conf.index].toJson());
if (!gladiators.contains(gladiatorToAttack.outputs[conf.index])) {
  return Response.forbidden(json.encode({
    "code": 0,
    "message": "Gladiator non inveni",
    "english": "Gladiator not found"
  }));
}
```

with the following output

```
{rationem: [{probationem: d24bb59f1b6d86fd0c6bb860faa204eb377289e9ad8ec4096a789fbf1bcf2ddf, interioreRationem: {publicaClavis: 043af38cfb7ff7cd65d73fe926cd3547aa143ab0041479ec19933a5732f3ad40aeb361b2ff64fa4d5ed79daefc569497c6d0c83cbc8748b6bbb51cbe2b5c264b30, nonce: 0, id: 6834a99b8b1880eaaf6eea1bf6d3475e3bc3b54de9c3b750a257a8b47fbbcf64}}], defensio: 6a}
{rationem: [{probationem: 0000eb7896fe02966d5690cfb5838d638f3b2e6761ea00bd09d735ba0911d58a, interioreRationem: {publicaClavis: 04282a6a6dbc6f3a255786db2ab4521f3b592a910262771b47d9b2847839413a9191c72c5dd8a7a3f4b7972c502062d600171464ee4c4db322966a5f3af089b02d, nonce: 155531, id: fcf1c5dac4d40b61b7e20ca078940d7d925e21f618ecdad300a45afba9a5d2b3}}], defensio: e8}
{rationem: [{probationem: 0000b7de2cf7b2e3c1c1849991d9ce3717c3cb536d42bac4fa7e603bd7c13231, interioreRationem: {publicaClavis: 049da1bcf3374b7aa543bc135134fd6cff416658447517a448b3cc929ce94fc151e6f3bde849d317b30484a03288cc48e92cdd168ff99838dfab900c32f3ff20d2, nonce: 65750, id: 3ebcb052e32663d89275591fd13dfffd33041b77aa216715d8f0cf96af968368}}], defensio: ef}
{rationem: [], defensio: cf}
{rationem: [], defensio: 75}
{rationem: [], defensio: 8e}
{rationem: [], defensio: b4}
{rationem: [], defensio: b4}
```

could someone tell me why contains is not giving true

Comment: Without seeing the contents of `gladiators` and `gladiatorToAttack.outputs` as well as what `conf.index` is, it's impossible to say. All I can tell you is that either you aren't comparing what you think you are comparing or the `GladiatorOutput` class doesn't override `==` correctly (if at all).

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67948628/9316174

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to tell without knowing the contents of gladiators, maybe print gladiators, and see if gladiatorToAttack.outputs[conf.index] is there, however also, your question says you would like to check "if the object is in the list",
but `!gladiators.contains(gladiatorToAttack.outputs[conf.index])` you're asking it in the code to check "if the object is NOT in the list",  clarify please what exactly you wanna do

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).