# flutter list contains check model not working

Tags: flutter, list

// ----- a list to store the favourites courses list

```
 List<FavouriteModel> _favCourses = [];

void initAddToFav(FavouriteModel model, BuildContext context) {
    if (_favCourses.contains(model)) {

      _courseController.removeFromFavourite(model);

      AlertHelper.showSanckBar(
          context, 'Remove from favourites !', AnimatedSnackBarType.error);

      notifyListeners();

    } else {

      _courseController.addToFavourite(model);

      AlertHelper.showSanckBar(
          context, 'Added to favourites !', AnimatedSnackBarType.success);

      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

When try check _favCourses.contains favourite model then if condition not working even data exsist else part working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether a list contain an attribute of an object in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757708/check-whether-a-list-contain-an-attribute-of-an-object-in-dart)

Comment: Are you handling the listeners of `ChangeNotifier` in widget
?

Comment: Please add a code where you used this `ChangeNotifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using .contains on a list of FavouriteModel objects. Dart doesn't automatically know how to test if one object is equal to another in the same way that it compares numbers or strings. So it will compare the item by memory address. That is unless you tell it how to test if the two objects are equal using a key.

Take a look at this answer here which uses a different way of checking if the list contains the item.

[Check whether a list contain an attribute of an object in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757708/check-whether-a-list-contain-an-attribute-of-an-object-in-dart)

Answer (score 1):

you are check wrong condition because you applied the condition on _favCourses list and perform the task in _courseController.

```
Correct your if condition

If(_courseController.contains(model))
  {
     _courseController.removeFromFavourite(model);
     AlertHelper.showSanckBar(context, 'Remove from favourites !', AnimatedSnackBarType.error);

  notifyListeners();
  }
```